# Laravel Dynamic model database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, model, laravel-5

I have a Model for DB tables, basically is one table but in different databases,
How can I set a connection to DB in Model?

```
protected $connection = 'ls';
```

Above code is not that I am looking for, I need to pass host, port, username and password. because conection are stored in DB not in config file.
I was thinking for `function __construct()` and call like `Model($data)::where()..etc`

Or I am thinking wrong way, can somebody give me an better idea.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect from Eloquent model by maintaining following aspects

**First you can define multiple connection in `database.php` file**

```
<?php
return array(

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),
);
```

You have your default connection still set to `mysql` . This means that, unless we specify otherwise, the application will use that `mysql` connection.

**Now in your model you can specify which connection to use**

```
<?php

class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

protected $connection = 'mysql2';

 }
```

**You can also define the connection at runtime via the setConnection method.**

```
 <?php

 class SomeController extends BaseController {

 public function someMethod()
 {
    $someModel = new SomeModel;

    $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');

    $something = $someModel->find(1);

    return $something;
}

}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I am looking for something else, the connection are stored in DB not in config file, And I need to pass the connection parameter like (host, username, pass) to a model.